# Evaluate limit $\lim_{n \to \infty } {1 \over n^{k + 1}}\left( {k! + {(k + 1)! \over 1!} + \cdots + {(k + n)! \over n!}} \right),k \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate the limit:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty } {1 \over n^{k + 1}}\left( {k! + {(k + 1)! \over 1!} + \cdots + {(k + n)! \over n!}} \right),k \in \mathbb{N}$$

It looks like a classic Cesaro-Stolz problem, but applying it didn't bring me any useful result.

I've been told the following equality might be helpful: $(1 - q)(1 + q + \cdots + q^N) = (1 - q^{N + 1})$

Comment: To write\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to \infty} instead of \lim_{n \to \infty} in _displayed_ MathJax is bizarre.  If it were inline, it could make sense to write \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}, but why write \mathop{\lim} when it's already a standard thing?  It seems like being complicated for the sake of being complicated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using MathType and didn't actually check the output it gives. Maybe changing the preferences will help?

Comment: Could be.... I've never used MathType.

Comment: You just type manually? Sometimes the expression is too complicated.

Comment: Stolz-Cesàro seems to work fine.  First show that $(k+n)!/n! \sim n^k$ using Stirling's formula, then show that $\sum_{m=0}^{n} m^k \sim \frac{1}{k+1} n^{k+1}$ by comparing the sum to $\int_0^n x^k\,dx$.

Comment: I cannot use Striling's formula, thanks though :)

Comment: Stirling's formula isn't necessary I guess.  Just notice $(k+n)!/n! = n^k \prod_{m=1}^k (1 + m/n)$, and the product tends to $1$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @AndrePoole Please state what you *can* and *cannot* use.

Comment: @AndrePoole : I've always typed everything manually.  Which expressions would you consider too complicated?

Comment: @MichaelHardy, There are cases where your expression is too "heavy". In those cases I'd prefer to write it with an editor, and not manually.

Comment: I surmise that MathType is some sort of software found on the web for creating MathJax code.  I don't know where things like this are found or how people find out that they exist.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, we use Google.

Comment: @AndrePoole : In order to use Google, wouldn't there first have to be something you're looking for?

Comment: Indeed. In this case, I searched for an easy way typing MathJax code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: It can be shown that
$$\sum_{m = 0}^n \frac{(k + m)!}{m!} = \frac{(n + 1)(k + n + 1)!}{(k + 1)(n + 1)!}.$$

You may find [this](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Rising_Sum_of_Binomial_Coefficients) formula useful.

If you then divide by $n^{k + 1}$ and take the limit as $n \to \infty$, you should get
$$\frac{1}{1 + k}.$$

**Edit**: Using Stirling's asymptotic formula $N! \sim N^N e^{-N}\sqrt{2\pi N}$, where $\sim$ denotes asymptotic equality, we have
$$\frac{(n + 1)(k + n + 1)!}{(n + 1)!} = \frac{(k + n + 1)!}{k^{k + 1}n!} \sim \frac{1}{n^{k + 1}} \frac{(k + n + 1)^{k + n + 1}e^{-(k + n + 1)}\sqrt{2\pi (k + n + 1)}}{n^n e^{-n}\sqrt{2\pi n}}.$$
If we simplify the right-hand side, we find that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n^{k + n + 3/2}(k + n + 1)^{k + n + 3/2}e^{k + 1}} &= \left(1 + \frac{k + 1}{n}\right)^{-(k + n + 3/2)} e^{-(k + 1)}\\
&= \left(1 - \frac{-(k + 1)}{n}\right)^{-(k + n + 3/2)} e^{-(k + 1)}\\
&= \left[\left(1 - \frac{-(k + 1)}{n}\right)^{(k + n + 3/2)}\right]^{-1} e^{-(k + 1)}\\
&\to e^{k + 1}e^{-(k + 1)} \quad (\text{as } n \to \infty)\\
&= 1
\end{align*}
because
$$e^{-x} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1 - \frac{x}{n}\right)^n$$
and $k + n + 3/2 \sim n$ as $n \to \infty$ since $k \in \mathbb{N}$ is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\lim_{n \to \infty }{1 \over n^{k + 1}}\bracks{%
     k! + {\pars{k + 1}! \over 1!} + \cdots + {\pars{k + n}! \over n!}}\,,\quad
     k \in \mathbb{N}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> &\lim_{n \to \infty }{1 \over n^{k + 1}}\bracks{%
> k! + {\pars{k + 1}! \over 1!} + \cdots + {\pars{k + n}! \over n!}}
> =\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n^{k + 1}}
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{\pars{k + \ell}! \over \ell!}
> \\[3mm]&=k!\,\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n^{k + 1}}
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}{k + \ell \choose k}
> =k!\,\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n^{k + 1}}
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}\int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{k + \ell} \over z^{k + 1}}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=k!\,\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n^{k + 1}}
> \int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{k} \over z^{k + 1}}
> \sum_{\ell = 0}^{n}\pars{1 + z}^{\ell}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=k!\,\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n^{k + 1}}
> \int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{k} \over z^{k + 1}}\,
> {\pars{1 + z}^{n + 1} - 1 \over \pars{1 + z} - 1}\,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}
> \\[3mm]&=k!\,\lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n^{k + 1}}
> \bracks{%
> \overbrace{%
> \int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{k + n + 1} \over z^{k + 2}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{=\ {k + n + 1 \choose k + 1}}}\
> -\
> \overbrace{%
> \int_{\verts{z} = 1}{\pars{1 + z}^{k} \over z^{k + 2}}
> \,{\dd z \over 2\pi\ic}}^{\ds{=\ 0}}}
> \\[3mm]&=k!\,
> \lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n^{k + 1}}\,{\pars{k + n + 1}! \over \pars{k + 1}!\,n!}
> \\[3mm]&={k! \over \pars{k + 1}!}\,
> \lim_{n \to \infty}{1 \over n^{k + 1}}\,
> {\root{2\pi}\pars{k + n + 1}^{k + n + 3/2}\expo{-n - k - 1} \over
> \root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n}}
> \\[3mm]&={1 \over k + 1}\,
> \overbrace{\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{1 + {k + 1 \over n}}^{k + n + 3/2}\expo{-k - 1}}
> ^{\ds{=\ 1}}
> \end{align}

$$\color{#00f}{\large%
\lim_{n \to \infty }{1 \over n^{k + 1}}\bracks{%
k! + {\pars{k + 1}! \over 1!} + \cdots + {\pars{k + n}! \over n!}}
={1 \over k + 1}}
$$

Comment: You should not make the proof more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Either way can't use integration. thanks though

Comment: @glebovg It's likely true. However, it's quite general and the technique is quite useful in more complicated situations. Once I saw the result I had the feeling there is a shorter way to do it but it was too late. That expression of the combinatoric in terms of a contour integral is quite useful. Thanks.

Comment: @FelixMarin Indeed. Using contour integration is perhaps a bit of overkill, but this general technique is quite useful nonetheless. Nice answer.

Comment: @glebovg The other answers just use the sum result without any derivation of it.

Answer (score 0):

Factor out the k!. Use the identity: 1 + C(k,k) + C(k+1,k) +...+ C(k+n,k) = C(k+n+1,k+1). Thus the expression equals: k!(n+k+1)!/((k+1)!n!n^(k+1)) = (1+1/n)(1+2/n)...(1+(k+1)/n)/(k+1) ---> **1/(k+1)** as n --> infinity.